# Access BPF maps via classic BPF

Tags: linux, bpf

Is it possible to access BPF maps using classic BPF? If so how? I suspect the answer is that you can't but I haven't seen it stated explicitly anywhere.

The [BPF helpers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) functions that allow you to access maps are not accessible to non-eBPF programs, but it's unclear if you could access the map using another method. It doesn't help that "BPF" seems to sometimes refer to classic BPF (cBPF) specifically, and sometimes to cBPF *and* eBPF.

Answer (score 3):

No, classic BPF (cBPF) has not support for maps whatsoever. They only work with eBPF.